# Angular Bootstrap Datepicker Issue

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-bootstrap

Using the [Angular Bootstrap calender](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and facing an issue.
When editing the input field the same date is displayed in the calender[image: like following]

But if i happen to navigate to another month and close the datepicker then the date in the input field is selected but not displayed in the calender., Say for example i moved from September to August , didnt made any selecttion and closed the datepicker then on reopening the calender rather then getting the date in the input field ie (16-Sept) i am getting August diplayed in the calender.[image: like this]

HTML -

```
<div data-ng-controller="dateCtrl as toDate">
                        <span class="span1 actionFilterSpan">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="aaa1">From</label> <br> 
                                    <input class="u-b"
                                        type="text" id="from1" 
                                        datepicker-popup="{{toDate.format}}"
                                        data-ng-model="ctrl.filterForm.fDate" 
                                        is-open="toDate.openedDP1"                                          
                                        datepicker-options="toDate.dateOptions"
                                        date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
                                        data-ng-required="true"
                                        close-text="Close" 
                                        data-ng-change="toDate.fromDateChange(ctrl.filterForm.fDate)"
                                        close-on-date-selection='true'/>

                                    <button type="button" 
                                        class="button-image1"
                                        data-ng-click="toDate.openDP1($event)">
                                        <img class="cal1" src="app/images/calIcon1.jpg">
                                    </button>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </div>                                  
                        </span> 
   </div>
```

Controller -

```
 var self = this;
  self.today = function() {
                    dateSvc.setToDate(new Date());
                    dateSvc.setFromDate(new Date());
                };

                self.today();

                self.clear = function() {
                    dateSvc.setToDate(null);
                    dateSvc.setFromDate(null);
                };



                self.openDP1 = function($event) {
                    $event.preventDefault();
                    $event.stopPropagation();
                    self.openedDP2 = false;
                    self.openedDP1 = !self.openedDP1;
                };
     self.fromDateChange = function(selectedDate){
                    dateSvc.setFromDate(selectedDate);
                    console.log(selectedDate);
                    self.filterForm = selectedDate;
                    console.log("MOdal Value : "+self.filterForm);
                };

                self.toDateChange = function(selectedDate){
                    dateSvc.setToDate(selectedDate);
                    console.log(selectedDate);
                };

                self.dateOptions = {
                    formatYear : 'yy',
                    formatMonth : 'MMM',
                    startingDay : 1
                };

                self.formats = [ 'dd-MMM-yyyy', 'dd-MMMM-yyyy',
                        'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate' ];
                self.format = self.formats[0];
```

Where datesvc is a service used to get and setdate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the date-picker when you are closing it.

Try this. Hope this will help

```
/**
 * Decorates the ui-bootstrap datepicker directive's controller to allow
 * refreshing the datepicker view (and rerunning invalid dates function) 
 * upon an event trigger: `$scope.$broadcast('refreshDatepickers');`

 * 
 * Works with inline and popup. Include this after `ui.bootstrap` js
 */

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.datepicker')
    .config(function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('datepickerDirective', function($delegate) {
            var directive = $delegate[0];
            var link = directive.link;

            directive.compile = function() {
                return function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
                    link.apply(this, arguments);

                    var datepickerCtrl = ctrls[0];
                    var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[1];

                    if (ngModelCtrl) {
                        // Listen for 'refreshDatepickers' event...
                        scope.$on('refreshDatepickers', function refreshView() {
                            datepickerCtrl.refreshView();
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
            return $delegate;
        });
    });
```

(1) Create a file called datepicker.decorator.js, and copy and paste the code above into it.

(2) Include it in your project, and add a script reference to datepicker.decorator.js after the script reference for ui-bootstrap.js

(3) In your own code, whenever you need to refresh the calendar, just call $scope.$broadcast('refreshDatepickers');

---

If it is not working for you there is an another way to achieve it.

Create a $on event in the datepicker.js file of the datepicker directive which you'll able to call from your controller. As I can see there is an inbuilt method **refreshView** which you can call it inside the $on Event.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Already tried this one , this doesnt works for me ! is there any other way to trigger the refresh event for datepickers

Comment: Worked the same way , broadcast an event on popup open and close and on event calls the refresh() , but it still retains the last state.         $rootScope.$broadcast('eventDP1Open',self.dt1);            And                            $scope.$on('eventDP1Open', function(event, value) {
  console.log("Value from on : "+value);
  self.refreshView();
    });

Comment: Refresh () is called everytime , but state is retained if i navigaed to some other month previously